# Get HostName from SSH arguments in a wrapper script

Tags: command-line, ssh, bash-scripting

I am developing a simple wrapper script for SSH to do some preprocessing before actually executing SSH (to be exact: load the per-host key with keychain/ssh-agent).

In order to do so, I need to extract the host name from the command line arguments. The wrapper shall support all options accepted by SSH — so my first, simple approch using the last command line parameter does not work if the user intends to run a command non-interactively on the remote side.

Does anybody see a simple shell-only way to get the hostname reliably?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a first pass, I would use `getopt` to loop through the `ssh` arguments.  The first non-option parameter should be either `hostname` or `user@hostname` (where `hostname` is a name, an IP address, or an alias from the ssh configuration file[s]).

Comment: `$(hostname) `?

Comment: @user4556274: I thought about this too, but wouldn't I then need to skip arguments to the options (such as for -o)? This would actually mean to name all SSH option in the script, right?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I'm looking for specifierd remote hostname, not the local one...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ssh -G`:

```
ssh -G -nNT -L10000:localhost:10000 admin@yo|grep "^hostname"|awk '{print $2}'
```

Will print `yo`. It will fully resolve to the real hostname if you have a match in your `.ssh/config`.